# Understanding PHP Legacy Code From 10 Year Old SaaS

Tags: php

I am working on a new project with some existing code. I have spent most of the night digging through code which is 10 years old. I am a little confused about a few things and am looking for some insight.

At the top of an template page there is this,

```
$template = <<<THEVERYENDOFYOU
```

and at the very end of the page there is this,

```
</table><br />
THEVERYENDOFYOU;
?>
```

I do not recall ever seeing `<<<` used in other sites I have worked on.

I also noticed some code like this throughout the site,

```
{{insertheader}}
</head>
<body {{insertonload}}><div id="container">
```

I am thinking maybe they used some type of framework? Does anyone recognize this or can you shoot me to some documentation explaining it?

Comment: heredoc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and some templeate

Comment: Hey thank you, So basically is this adding the full template page to a string = template then somewhere else they are just calling template as a string?

Comment: What about the second example? I was thinking maybe that was some js but its not in any <script> tags.

Comment: {{}} Is often used to evoke attributes/variables from your code. It is widely used in template engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example of `<<<` is [HereDocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) - simple alternative to code between `""`.

Second example is simple placeholders to be replaced when processing HTML. It may be any framework or even simple text-replace algorithm

Comment: `simple alternative to code between ""` not really they have quite a few diffrences

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, maybe my non-native English is wrong. I mean `You can think of it as alternative to ""`. Still, link to Docs provides full info